# mySQL sum from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that look roughly like this:

1. **employment_projections**: some value (pvalue) and a data_type(fk pointing to data_type table)

[**pvalue, data_type**] 
1232, 001
2321, 001
1232, 003
446,  001
123,  002

2. **data_type**: codes and a description for each code 
   [**code, description**] 
   001, this is code 1
   002, this is code 2
   ....

I need a query that will give me each description for each data_type and the sum of the values that use the code from the projections table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query should give you the expected result:

```
select type.id, type.description, sum(value) as sum
from data_type type join pvalue val on type.id = val.typeId
group by type.id, type.description
```

Comment: I cannot make sense of your query. It seems I worded my question poorly, so I have edited it to include more information.